# Populate returns whole parent document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I just started learning express and mongodb. I recently faced the kind of problem, I'm trying to select all the subdocuments which are inside of `Room` model.

```
const books = await Room.find().populate('book');
```

But it returns whole room document when i want to select only `bookings` field.

Here's the book schema

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  startDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  endDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("book", bookSchema)
```

And here's the room schema

```
const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  currentlyReserved: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  people: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  roomNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  pricePerPerson: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  reservedUntil: {
    type: Date,
    default: null,
  },
  reservedBy: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
  },
  bookings: {
    type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "book" }],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("room", roomSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can project with with second arg to find().

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection

```
const books = await Room.find({}, {bookings: 1}).populate('bookings');
```